# Local UWP client to local asp.net core api web server - The certificate authority is invalid or incorrect

Tags: c#, asp.net, uwp, certificate, client-certificates

I'm taking over someone else's project and trying to get the front-end (UWP) to talk to the backend (asp.net core 2.x api).

They independently work and the backend, on debug, opens a browser to the proper route, https://localhost:44319/api/status. When I try to connect the front-end to the backend, I get `The certificate authority is invalid or incorrect`

The code uses HttpClient.

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient(new 
HttpClientHandler() { UseDefaultCredentials = true });
var uri = new Uri(string.Format(accountListServiceUri, string.Empty));
var response = await client.GetAsync(uri);
```

I'm running the backend via IISExpress and I used the following powershell script to get the thumbnail of the IIS Express dev cert.

```
View certificate Copy Set-Location Cert:\LocalMachine\My Get-ChildItem | Format-Table Subject, FriendlyName, Thumbprint
```

I used the thumbnail to make a pfx file.

```
Get-ChildItem -Path cert:\localMachine\my\<THUMBNAIL> | Export-PfxCertificate -FilePath C:\<PROJECTNAME>.pfx -Password $mypwd
```

Then I imported the pfx into both the Trusted Root Certificate Authority and Trusted People based on different SO answers.

I *think* the server is set up correctly, but the client is not. I would like to resolve this issue without putting in #debug code as that won't pass security checks.

Thank you for any help.

Comment: You mentioned the certificate but I did not see that you set [certificate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.web.http.filters.httpbaseprotocolfilter.clientcertificate#Windows_Web_Http_Filters_HttpBaseProtocolFilter_ClientCertificate) for your http  GET request in your code.

Comment: There's a similar issue on GitHub(https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/3145#issuecomment-425281194).

Comment: @XavierXie-MSFT How do I add a certificate to the HTTPClient request?

Answer (score 9):

The fix was to configure the UWP package manifest's capabilities included **Shared User Certificates**. [image]